# Observer won't run update in JavaFX GUI

Tags: multithreading, javafx, observers

I read much about the JavaFX GUI Model, `Plattform->RunLater` and Threads, but I still do not figure out how to get this right. I had a JavaFX GUI which on a button click executed a process and updated a Progress Bar and Label. This was running well with Threading and Platform, but I had to Change this to an Observer Model.

I invoke a Progress Tracker in a Singleton Model, which gets updated by the class executing the process and is Observable. I implemented an Observer as well which should update the two UI Elements.

GUI Controller with Button Event

```
private void createKeyPressed(ActionEvent event) {

    // Make Progressbar visible
    pbKeyProgress.visibleProperty().set(true);

    if (!Check.keyFileExistant() || cbKeyOverwrite.selectedProperty().get()) {
        ProgressTracker.getTracker().addObserver(new ProgressObserver(pbKeyProgress, lblKeyProgress));
        Creator.createKey(cbKeyLength.getValue());
    } else {
    }
}
```

Progress Observer

```
public class ProgressObserver implements Observer {

    private final ProgressBar progressBar;
    private final Label statusLabel;

    public ProgressObserver(ProgressBar progressBar, Label statusLabel) {

        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.statusLabel = statusLabel;
    }

    @Override

    public void update(Observable o, Object o1) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            System.out.println("Tracker set to "+ProgressTracker.getProgress() + " " + ProgressTracker.getStatus());
            progressBar.setProgress(ProgressTracker.getProgress());
            statusLabel.setText(ProgressTracker.getStatus());
        });

    }

}
```

Progress Tracker

```
    public synchronized void setTracker(int currentStep, String currentStatus) {

    checkInstance();
    instance.step = currentStep;
    instance.status = currentStatus;
    instance.notifyObservers();
    System.out.println(instance.countObservers());
}
```

Creator

```
public static void createKey(String length) {

    Task<Void> task;
    task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            initTracker(0,"Start");
            doStuff();
            ProgressTracker.getTracker().setTracker(1,"First");
            doStuff();
            ProgressTracker.getTracker().setTracker(2,"Second");
            // and so on

            return null;

        }
    };

    new Thread(task)
            .start();

}
```

The Print within the ProgressTracker gets executed. However, if I add a print within the update of the Observer nothing will be printed. If I check within the Progresstracker, the Observer Count is 1.

Why does the Observer not get notified or execute anything, even if the Notify is called? Did I get the Threading and Execution Modell wrong?
The Progress Bar and the Label will also stay on their initial values.

Comment: I recommend you to read [that](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/javafx/javafx-concurrent-framework/) article.

Comment: The threading all looks correct. Probably the error is elsewhere in your code (try to create a [MCVE] if you can't figure it out). You are really reinventing the wheel, though: the [JavaFX properties pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) is a ready-made implementation of the Observer pattern, which is far more convenient to use than writing your own implementation. You can also call the task's `updateProgress()` and `updateMessage()` methods, and then just bind the progress bar and label to the appropriate properties of the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. The [JavaFX Properties Pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) is a ready-made implementation of the Observable pattern: there is no need to implement it yourself. Additionally, `Task` already defines methods for updating various properties, which can be called from any thread but will schedule the actual updates on the FX Application Thread. See [`updateProgress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateProgress-long-long-) and [`updateMessage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateMessage-java.lang.String-), for example.

So you can do, for example:

```
public static Task<Void> createKey(String length) {

    Task<Void> task;
    task = new Task<Void>() {

        final int totalSteps = ... ;
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            updateProgress(0, totalSteps);
            updateMessage("Start");
            doStuff();
            updateProgress(1, totalSteps);
            updateMessage("First");
            doStuff();
            updateProgress(2, totalSteps);
            updateMessage("Second");
            // and so on

            return null;

        }
    };

    new Thread(task)
            .start();

    return task ;

}
```

and

```
private void createKeyPressed(ActionEvent event) {

    // Make Progressbar visible
    pbKeyProgress.visibleProperty().set(true);

    if (!Check.keyFileExistant() || cbKeyOverwrite.selectedProperty().get()) {
        Task<Void> task = Creator.createKey(cbKeyLength.getValue());
        pbKeyProgress.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        lblKeyProgress.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this seems interesting, but i have to try and fully understand it before i can mark your answer. One Problem is, the creator has to work for CLI and GUI and i wanted to use the ProgressTracker to unify Status Updates and have 2 different Observers, one for CLI and one for GUI. I will check if this model with Propertys works for both modes and if mark this as correct. But thank you already for the help!

Comment: @chenino It should be reasonably straightforward to factor out the code that needs to be reusable in a sensible way.

Comment: yes, it seems to me like this. As said, i will verify this and will mark this as correct then. Thank You :) (Somehow @ James_D  without the Space gets deleted)